# ConTeXt specifying font

Tags: fonts, context, fontfamily

I wanted to know how it was possible to use the numbers of another font. Let me explain.

If I want to use the greek characters of a font that is not the main one, I can make a fontfallback for example, like:

```
\definefallbackfamily [mainface] [serif] [Font Name] [range={greekandcoptic,greekextended}]
```

What is the equivalent of having all numbers 0123456789 (from U+0030 - U-0039) taken from another font other than the non-primary one?

In other words, how do you go about using Comic Sans numbers (all kind of, footnotes, pagenumbers etc.) when the main text uses Garamond?

Comment: Welcome to TeX S.E! Complete MWE are always welcome, not just the line you gave. It saves time and you will find more people willing to help.

Comment: Thank you very much, my apologies.

Answer (score 2):

To get the digits from a fallback font you can use `digitsnormal` as argument for the `range` key but you have to add `force=yes`.

```
\definefallbackfamily [garamaond_sans] [rm] [Comic Sans MS]
  [range=digitsnormal,
   force=yes,
   rscale=0.85]

\definefontfamily [garamaond_sans] [rm] [EB Garamond]

\setupbodyfont [garamaond_sans]

\starttext

\starttabulate
\dostepwiserecurse
  {0}{9}{1}
  {\expanded{\NC \convertnumber{Word}{\recurselevel} \NC \recurselevel \NC\NR}}
\stoptabulate

\stoptext
```

Comment: When I can I will try and let you know, thanks for now!